Three cards picked after rolling two dice - probability that two of these will be of same colour/rank
This is a problem that a grade 10 student constructed in response to a challenge the teacher gave the class to think up "difficult" problems using dice and cards:
There is a shuffled stack of playing cards with ranks $2$ to $10$, of hearts and diamonds suits. Let's call these "red" cards.
Similarly there is a shuffled stack of playing cards with ranks $2$ to $10$, of spades and club suits. Let's call these "black" cards.
So, we have $18$ red cards and $18$ black cards.
Now, we roll $2$ dice. Then we pick $3$ cards as follows:

If the number on the first die is even, we pick a red card, or else we pick a black card
Likewise for the second die - if it shows an even number, pick a red card, or else a black card
Likewise for the total of both dice - if it's even, pick a red card, or else a black card

What is the probability that among the $3$ cards picked, we will get two cards of the same colour (either red or black) with the same rank?
I have tried to work this out and have got an answer of $4/51\approx 7.84\%$  - but it's possible that I may have made a mistake in the calculations. Will share my solution/approach separately.

there are only $4$ equally probable cases:  $(E,E), (E,O), (O,E), (O,O)$  Where $E$ stands for Even and $O$ for odd.  You only need to consider the first and last (and by symmetry you only need to consider one of these).

@lulu I agree with all but the last sentence of your original comment.  It breaks into effectively two cases, all cards drawn from the same pile, or two cards drawn from one pile and one from another.  (E,E) corresponds to all cards drawn from same pile and has a different associated probability of the event in question than each of (E,O),(O,E), and (O,O).

@JMoravitz  Oh, you are right.  I was only thinking of two draws, not three.

To begin, note that the parity of the die rolls are independent events.  We have then (E,E), (E,O), (O,E), and (O,O) are all equally likely to occur.
For these, note that (E,E) will have all three cards drawn from the red deck.  Meanwhile, each of the remaining three cases will have two cards drawn from the same deck and one card drawn from a different deck.  (Remember, odd + odd is not odd).
Examining each case separately, we have if all three cards came from the same deck, this will avoid having repeated ranks with probability $\frac{16\cdot 14}{17\cdot 16} = \frac{14}{17}$, and therefore will have a repeated rank with probability $1-\frac{14}{17} = \frac{3}{17}$.
(To explain this calculation further, we begin with 18 red cards and the first card can be any red card.  After having picked that card, to avoid a repeated rank we have $16$ remaining red cards that avoid that rank out of $17$ total remaining cards.  After having picked so as to avoid, we have $14$ remaining who avoid matching either previously selected out of $16$ total remaining cards)
Next, for all other cases we only have two cards being pulled from the black deck that can match color and rank.  By a similar calculation as before, we have probability $1 - \frac{16}{17}$ that they match rank.
Our probability then of having a matching color/rank pair will be:
$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{3}{17} + \frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{17} = \frac{3}{34}$$

The total number of cards in the red deck is 18. So, the probability of avoiding repeated ranks when drawing 3, would be (16/17) x (14/16) = 14/17, and therefore probability of having a repeated rank would be 1 - (14/17) = 3/17. Correct?

@KeenMonk I did have an off by one error in counting the cards somehow.  $\frac{3}{17}$ is correct given that we were drawing three cards from the red deck, but this then is used in a later final calculation.
